# Where can I find references for how to build interlinear gloss for Chinese?

Tags: interlinear-gloss, chinese

I find building interlinear gloss for Chinese to be difficult without any sort of reference material for what to call different grammatical particles etc. Is there such a reference available online?

Comment: There is a short manual with the general conventions for linguistic glosses, which you can access [here](http://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php). As for the particular elements of Chinese grammar, perhaps [this](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~karchung/linguistics%20links.htm#chingloss) can help you find what you need.